# How do I configure Eclipse (which lives on the host) to see the remote Tomcat (the one that lives on the guest)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vagrant

I am using vagrant and have created a VM with Ubuntu 12.04, I have synced my java web app, installed tomcat7 and java7 on my VM. Now I have two instances of my code, one on on Host machine and other in my Gues(VM). I want to run the code from my Host(Mac-OSX) machine using Eclipse. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to develop with your host and serve the files from your vm's server?

Comment: @Stefan: yes you got me right.

Comment: You cannot easily do so.  This is essentially a situation with two machines with a shared directory and nothing more, so the traditional solutions about developing against a remote Tomcat server applies.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Thanks for the answer, but as an alternative we can do this through command prompt by just hosting the code on the guest tomcat and serve it from there. Will that be possible as I am new to java, sorry if it sounds weard to you.

Comment: If you are new to Java I would suggest you get accustomed to Tomcat development locally before venturing into multi-host scenarios.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Your suggestion is welcomed, but currently I am handling the responsibility to create a development environment for my team, so I just need to ensure that this is possible. Rest the other developers will take care of.

Comment: Possible, sure; easy to work with, not so sure.

Comment: Unless you have very, very good reason to, then _develop_ on a local Tomcat/Jetty instance well integrated with your IDE of choice.  It will be much faster and less tedious.  You can then _test_ the result on a Docker instance if needed and adjust accordingly.